# Google Cloud Speech to text returning empty result or error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

Working hard for 4 days now to fix the google cloud speech to text api to work, but still see no light at the end of the tunnel. Searched on the net a lot, read the documentations a lot but see no result.

Our site is bbsradio.com, we are trying to auto extract transcript from our mp3 files using google speech-to-text api. Code is written on PHP and almost exact copy of this: `https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/src/transcribe_async.php`
I see process is completed and its reached out here "`$operation->pollUntilComplete();`" but its not showing it was successful at "`if ($operation->operationSucceeded()) {`" and its not returning any error either at `$operation->getError()`.

I am converting the mp3 to raw file like this: `ffmpeg -y -loglevel panic -i /public_html/sites/default/files/show-archives/audio-clips-9-23-2020/911freefall2020-05-24.mp3 -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -vn -ac 1 -ar 16000 -map_metadata -1 /home/mp3_to_raw/911freefall2020-05-24.raw`

While tried with FLAC format as well, not worked. I tested converted FLAC file using windows media player, I can listen conversation clearly. I checked the files its Hz 16000, channel = 1 and its 16 bit. I see file is uploaded in cloud storage. Checked this:

`https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/troubleshooting` and
`https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices`

There are lot of discussion and documentation, seems nothing is helpful at this moment. If some one can really help me out to find out the issue, it will be really really really great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I found the solution and reason of the issue. Actually getting empty results is a bug of the php api code. What you need to do:

Replace this:

```
$operation->pollUntilComplete();
```

by this:

```
while(!$operation->isDone()){
       $operation->pollUntilComplete();
}
```

Read this: [enter link description here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/issues/2611)

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; convert from MP3 to a 1-channel FLAC file with the same sample rate as your MP3 file.

Long explanation:

Since you're using MP3 files as your process input, *probably* you MP3 compression artifacts might be hurting you when you resample to to 16KHz (you cannot hear this, but the algoritm *will*).

To confirm this theory:

- Execute `ffprobe -hide_banner filename.mp3` it will output something like this:

```
  Metadata:
    ...
  Duration: 00:02:12.21, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 320 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : LAME3.99r
```

- In this case, the sample rate is OK for Google-Spech-Api. Just transcode the file without changing the sample rate (remove the -ar 16000 from your ffmpeg command)
- You might get into trouble if the original MP3 bitrate is low. 320kb/s seems safe (unless the recording has a lot of noise).
- Take into account that voice recoded under 64kb/s (ISDN line quality) can be understood only by humans if there is some noise.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried with the suggestion. Still not working.

I tried with a proven mp3 file, I see its working, so code is okay. The mp3 file which I am testing has 32000 Hz, 80 kb/s bitrate, channel 2 (converted to flac with mono). There is some related to mp3 file parameter for sure.

Comment: @Md.ShafiqHossain - Sorry to hear that. MP3 is good for archiving sound for humans. Machines have problems with that currently. I don'k know about a MP3 -> to simple wave reconstructor (with super resolution) that works. Still a work-in-progress.

Comment: I tried with a wav file, still no success.
WAV file parameter is as follows:
Duration: 01:57:52.82, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s

Converted into FLAC like this:
Duration: 01:57:52.82, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 153 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 16000 Hz, mono, s16
<br>
Also tried with 44100 Hz, same result no success.